# Dotfuscator 4.10 project in VS 2012 bugs while trying to save .dotfuproj file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dotfuscator

I recently installed Dotfuscator 4.10 on my computer and I already has VS 2012 working on it. Everything worked fine up to the point when I tried Dotfuscator embedded in VS (I mean the standalone GUI app works perfectly).

Just for the try, I created a small solution (no TFS/VSS) with a C++ /clr app, a C++/clr dll and a C# app.

I then added a Dotfuscator project. To this project I added the output from the three dll/exe other projects.

When I tried to rebuild the solution, I was asked to save the .dotfuproj file. Strange and  abnormal behaviour, the file should be saved automatically and without prompting me. OK, I chose to overwrite the existing file (what should have been done automatically after all.) I got the error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** I had to cancel the operation and could not build the solution.

Note that I observed the same behaviour if I tried to save the dotfuproj file under an other name. Also, the file  **is not R/O**.

My question: has someone experienced this problem? Any solution? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting your Dotfuscator project and then creating a new project.  If that does not work, try using direct input to the Dotfuscator project, rather than using the output of another project within your solution.